# Can I actually say "he is being sick"? Does it sound natural?

Tags: progressive-aspect, present-participles, be, being

Here is my question: Can I say "he is being sick"?
I was looking for how to use *been* and *being.*

What I have found:

> The word **being** is the present participle form of the verb **be**.
>   It is not used after **have**. As a rule, being is used after a form
>   of be (is, am, are, was, were).
>
> - He is being sick. (= He is vomiting.) (NOT He has being sick.)
> - Who is being a silly baby, then?
> - I was being careful.

([English Practice: Difference between being and been](http://www.englishpractice.com/common-mistakes/difference-9/))

Some guy said I could not use "he is being sick" because it sounds unnatural.

Comment: In the context of saying he is currently vomiting, "he is being sick" is perfectly valid. Some guy is wrong.

Comment: Second that. "Some guy" is apparently unfamiliar with even slightly good English.

Comment: I think *some guy* is not making the connection between *being sick* and *vomiting*. *He is being ill* would certainly sound unnatural, outside of India.

Comment: Actually, "some guy" makes sense. The third line ("He is being ...") answers your question. His last two lines are cheeky examples of using the word "being".

Comment: Lawrence, "some guy" in this case is whoever told OP that "he is being sick" wasn't valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been mentioned, "being sick" is often used as a polite euphemism for "vomiting", and is widely used for that purpose.

I suspect that your friend was referring to a person being ill (feeling miserable, suffering a disease, etc), and in that case he or she was correct. Ordinarily you would say "He is sick" rather than "He is being sick".

Generally, the construction "He is being (something)" is used when (something) is a matter of choice, such as "He is being greedy", or "He is being obstinate" or "He is being generous", while being sick is not a matter of choice.

I can imagine an exception, but it is considerably involved. Let's say a mutual friend is well-known for his hypochondria, and has claimed it repeatedly when it seems to conveniently remove him from some obligation. You might say to another friend, "Don't expect to see him today. He has a paper due, and he hasn't finished it, so he's being sick." Here, "being sick" is used as a sarcastic replacement for "malingering".

Comment: @Mikhail - thanks for the vote. However, it's generally best to wait for 24 hours before selecting an answer. You never know when a better answer will come along, or someone else may point out that the answer is wrong. And really, there's no hurry.